# Unable to delete unwanted system keychains

Tags: keychain

I've two System Keychains I am unable to delete. "Local" and "fastlane_tmp_keychain-db". How do I delete these? All options are grayed-out when right clicking as well as Edit -> Delete.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Running `security list-keychains` in the terminal gave me a list of the keychains where the two mentioned were included:

```
oskar@Oskars-Mac-mini ~> security list-keychains
    "/Users/oskar/Library/Keychains/Local.keychain-db"
    "/Users/oskar/Library/Keychains/fastlane_tmp_keychain-db"
    "/Users/oskar/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db"
    "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
```

However, the files does not exist. Running `security delete-keychain <path>` returned an error on both:

```
oskar@Oskars-Mac-mini ~> security delete-keychain /Users/oskar/Library/Keychains/fastlane_tmp_keychain-db
security: SecKeychainDelete: The specified keychain could not be found.
```

But running `security list-keychains` again shows that they were deleted

```
oskar@Oskars-Mac-mini ~ [50]> security list-keychains
    "/Users/oskar/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db"
    "/Library/Keychains/System.keychain"
```

And when restarting Keychain Access, they are deleted there too.